# Add Total Row in SQL Query (Pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using a asset management software and unfortunatly unable to get the proper support in DIY implementation. I was looking to get an asset report (Laptop Count based on model and state).

With the help of google I manage to create a pivot for the required report. Now, I am stuck with the last part of the task. which is to get a total row for asset state e.g. (In - Store, New - In Store) at the bottom.

This is the Query and I am unable to understand how to add the total row.

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  ISNULL([In Use], 0.) + ISNULL([Used - In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([New - In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([Damaged], 0.) + ISNULL([Faulty], 0.) AS TOTAL 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      max("product"."COMPONENTNAME") AS "Product", 
      max("state"."DISPLAYSTATE") AS "Asset State", 
      count("resource"."RESOURCENAME") AS "Asset Count" 
    FROM 
      "Resources" "resource" 
      LEFT JOIN "ComponentDefinition" "product" ON "resource"."COMPONENTID" = "product"."COMPONENTID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceState" "state" ON "resource"."RESOURCESTATEID" = "state"."RESOURCESTATEID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceOwner" "rOwner" ON "resource"."RESOURCEID" = "rOwner"."RESOURCEID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceAssociation" "rToAsset" ON "rOwner"."RESOURCEOWNERID" = "rToAsset"."RESOURCEOWNERID" 
      LEFT JOIN "SDUser" "sdUser" ON "rOwner"."USERID" = "sdUser"."USERID" 
      LEFT JOIN "AaaUser" "aaaUser" ON "sdUser"."USERID" = "aaaUser"."USER_ID" 
    WHERE 
      product.COMPONENTNAME LIKE ('Thinkpad%') 
    GROUP BY 
      "product"."COMPONENTNAME", 
      "state"."DISPLAYSTATE"
  ) d pivot (
    sum("Asset Count") for "Asset State" in (
      [In Use], [Used - In Store], [In Store], 
      [New - In Store], [Damaged], [Faulty]
    )
  ) piv
```

[image]

Comment: What pivot are you referring to? I don't see any use of `PIVOT` or `UNPIVOT` in your query. Also, you can add a Total row by using [`GROUP BY ROLLUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Also, you don't need to enquote _everything_ - you can remove all of those `"` quotes and the query will be a lot more readable. You only need to enquote identifiers using reserved keywords or [_irregular_-identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @Dai apologies and thanks for pointing. I missed the pivot part in the query

Comment: You just overwiped all my pretty formatting :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY ... WITH CUBE` to automatically generate totals in both dimensions. This will add a totals row and will also eliminate the need to explicitly calculate the totals column.

```
SELECT piv.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
      ISNULL(product."COMPONENTNAME", 'Totals:') AS "Product", 
      ISNULL(state."DISPLAYSTATE", 'TOTAL') AS "Asset State", 
      count(resource."RESOURCENAME") AS "Asset Count" 
    FROM 
      "Resources" "resource" 
      LEFT JOIN "ComponentDefinition" "product" ON "resource"."COMPONENTID" = "product"."COMPONENTID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceState" "state" ON "resource"."RESOURCESTATEID" = "state"."RESOURCESTATEID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceOwner" "rOwner" ON "resource"."RESOURCEID" = "rOwner"."RESOURCEID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceAssociation" "rToAsset" ON "rOwner"."RESOURCEOWNERID" = "rToAsset"."RESOURCEOWNERID" 
      LEFT JOIN "SDUser" "sdUser" ON "rOwner"."USERID" = "sdUser"."USERID" 
      LEFT JOIN "AaaUser" "aaaUser" ON "sdUser"."USERID" = "aaaUser"."USER_ID" 
    WHERE 
      product.COMPONENTNAME LIKE ('Thinkpad%') 
    GROUP BY 
      product."COMPONENTNAME", 
      state."DISPLAYSTATE"
      WITH CUBE
) d
pivot (
    sum("Asset Count") for "Asset State" in (
      [In Use], [Used - In Store], [In Store], 
      [New - In Store], [Damaged], [Faulty],
      [TOTAL])
) piv
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN piv.Product = 'Totals:' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
    piv.Product
```

`ISNULL()` is used to assign labels to the grouped product and status names, which would otherwise be null. `[Total]` has also been added to the pivot list and removed from the final select list. You may need to edit the select list to add `ISNULL()` functions if you want to replace null values with zeros. (E.g., `ISNULL([In Use], 0) AS [In Use], ...`)

Results:

| Product | In Use | Used - In Store | In Store | New - In Store | Damaged | Faulty | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Thinkpad 101 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| Thinkpad 102 | 1 | null | null | null | null | null | 1 |
| Thinkpad 103 | null | null | null | null | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Totals: | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 13 |

You can also code a similar result using `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` for the rows together with "conditional aggregation" to define the columns as a replacement for the pivot.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(product.COMPONENTNAME, 'Total') AS Product,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN state.DISPLAYSTATE = 'In Use' THEN 1 END) AS [In Use],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN state.DISPLAYSTATE = 'Used - In Store' THEN 1 END) AS [Used - In Store],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN state.DISPLAYSTATE = 'In Store' THEN 1 END) AS [In Store],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN state.DISPLAYSTATE = 'New - In Store' THEN 1 END) AS [New - In Store],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN state.DISPLAYSTATE = 'Damaged' THEN 1 END) AS [Damaged],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN state.DISPLAYSTATE = 'Faulty' THEN 1 END) AS [Faulty],
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM 
      "Resources" "resource" 
      LEFT JOIN "ComponentDefinition" "product" ON "resource"."COMPONENTID" = "product"."COMPONENTID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceState" "state" ON "resource"."RESOURCESTATEID" = "state"."RESOURCESTATEID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceOwner" "rOwner" ON "resource"."RESOURCEID" = "rOwner"."RESOURCEID" 
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceAssociation" "rToAsset" ON "rOwner"."RESOURCEOWNERID" = "rToAsset"."RESOURCEOWNERID" 
      LEFT JOIN "SDUser" "sdUser" ON "rOwner"."USERID" = "sdUser"."USERID" 
      LEFT JOIN "AaaUser" "aaaUser" ON "sdUser"."USERID" = "aaaUser"."USER_ID" 
    WHERE 
      product.COMPONENTNAME LIKE ('Thinkpad%') 
GROUP BY product.COMPONENTNAME WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(product.COMPONENTNAME) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    product.COMPONENTNAME
```

"Conditional aggregation" is an informal term for usieng aggregation functions like `SUM()` or `COUNT()` together with a `CASE` expression. If the condition is true, the `THEN` clause provides the data to be aggregated. When false, the implicit `ELSE null` value is ignored.

Results:

| Product | In Use | Used - In Store | In Store | New - In Store | Damaged | Faulty | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Thinkpad 101 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| Thinkpad 102 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Thinkpad 103 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Total | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 13 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WZCcCFOg) for examples of both using simplified test data.

Comment: @T N Thanks CUBE method worked in my environment, not sure why the rollup is giving string error -1. Thanks for your support and fiddle it really helped me to understand and test the logic

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'UNION' to join two queries together to give you a total row; it'd be something like:

```
SELECT *, ISNULL([In Use], 0.) + ISNULL([Used - In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([New - In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([Damaged], 0.) + ISNULL([Faulty], 0.) AS TOTAL
FROM (
SELECT max("product"."COMPONENTNAME") AS "Product", max("state"."DISPLAYSTATE") AS "Asset State", count("resource"."RESOURCENAME") AS "Asset Count" FROM "Resources" "resource"
LEFT JOIN "ComponentDefinition" "product" ON "resource"."COMPONENTID"="product"."COMPONENTID"
LEFT JOIN "ResourceState" "state" ON "resource"."RESOURCESTATEID"="state"."RESOURCESTATEID"
LEFT JOIN "ResourceOwner" "rOwner" ON "resource"."RESOURCEID"="rOwner"."RESOURCEID" LEFT JOIN "ResourceAssociation" "rToAsset" ON "rOwner"."RESOURCEOWNERID"="rToAsset"."RESOURCEOWNERID" LEFT JOIN "SDUser" "sdUser" ON "rOwner"."USERID"="sdUser"."USERID" LEFT JOIN "AaaUser" "aaaUser" ON "sdUser"."USERID"="aaaUser"."USER_ID"
WHERE product.COMPONENTNAME LIKE 'ThinkPad %'
GROUP BY "product"."COMPONENTNAME","state"."DISPLAYSTATE")d

UNION

SELECT "Totals:", ISNULL([In Use], 0.) + ISNULL([Used - In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([New - In Store], 0.) + ISNULL([Damaged], 0.) + ISNULL([Faulty], 0.) AS TOTAL
FROM (
SELECT max("product"."COMPONENTNAME") AS "Product", max("state"."DISPLAYSTATE") AS "Asset State", count("resource"."RESOURCENAME") AS "Asset Count" FROM "Resources" "resource"
LEFT JOIN "ComponentDefinition" "product" ON "resource"."COMPONENTID"="product"."COMPONENTID"
LEFT JOIN "ResourceState" "state" ON "resource"."RESOURCESTATEID"="state"."RESOURCESTATEID"
LEFT JOIN "ResourceOwner" "rOwner" ON "resource"."RESOURCEID"="rOwner"."RESOURCEID" LEFT JOIN "ResourceAssociation" "rToAsset" ON "rOwner"."RESOURCEOWNERID"="rToAsset"."RESOURCEOWNERID" LEFT JOIN "SDUser" "sdUser" ON "rOwner"."USERID"="sdUser"."USERID" LEFT JOIN "AaaUser" "aaaUser" ON "sdUser"."USERID"="aaaUser"."USER_ID"
WHERE product.COMPONENTNAME LIKE 'ThinkPad %'
GROUP BY "state"."DISPLAYSTATE")d
```

Comment: I tried with Union and Union all but it will give an error for column 'In Use' not found or Query will not execute. While posting the question I missed the pivot part in query.